# Induced representations of compact groups

Tags: general-topology, representation-theory, topological-groups, galois-representations

I am taking a seminar that follows Serre's book "Linear Representations of Finite Groups", and I am preparing a talk on Chapter 7 on induced representations (Frobenius reciprocity, Mackey's formula for $Res_H Ind^G_H(W)$ and Mackey's irreducibility criterion).

Serre says on p. 34 that one can induce a representation from a finite index closed subgroup $H$ of a compact group $G$ to $G$ in the same way as for $G$ finite. 
Why is this true? I am wondering whether also the results from Chapter 7 carry over to $G$ compact?

Is there a reference for the representation theory of compact groups in general?

Thank you!

Comment: The point is that all the results that were proved using averaging arguments over the group (Weil's unitary trick, maschkes theorem etc) work for compact groups too, where the Haar measure is used instead of summing over elements of the group. Chapter 2 of [these notes](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/representation-theory-notes.pdf) is a great resource for defining all the formalism of representation theory (induction, restriction, characters etc) without any unnecessary assumptions on the group, finite-dimensionality and characteristic.